# SBT Downloads or Resolves Jar each time when code is compiled

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy

When I compile sbt-scala project, for each compilation the sbt is downloading or resolving jar even though the jar is available in `.ivy2` cache and it's taking a huge time for assembly.

When I use Maven, Dependency resolution is done once and the component will never try to download the same dependency if exist in `.M2` and all project will refer the dependency from `.M2` directly

Please tell me is there any way to stop this resolution or download when the jar is already available in `.ivy2` cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sbt set to work offline:

> When offline := true, remote SNAPSHOTs will not be updated by a resolution, even an explicitly requested update. This should effectively support working without a connection to remote repositories. Reproducible examples demonstrating otherwise are appreciated. Obviously, update must have successfully run before going offline.

quote from [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html)

If you can skip the update phase. Form the sbt shell:

> set skip in update := true

If you want to use just the cached artifact add to your build.sbt

```
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

My personal preference is to [override default repos](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) and add my local maven repo ( so resolution happens but is blazing fast)

Someone has gone [really far](http://codecraft.vaamo.de/2015/03/19/the-travelers-guide-towards-offline-scala-development.html) with this problem setting up a huge stack ( interesting but not suggested)

Comment: I tried giving **offline := true** in build.sbt the problem is not solved. While compiling the project it is trying to download from external repo.

Comment: try with interactive mode and set the value from set shell > set offline := true

Comment: I tried that as well. I use ./sbt to enter into interactive shell and gave set offline := true. But unfortunately it is still trying to resolve the dependency that is already available.                                                                               [info] Resolving com.cloudera.cdh#cdh-root;5.3.8 ...

Comment: are you using set version 0.13 ?

Comment: sbt.version=0.13.8 This is the version I am using.

Comment: I edited my answer... with this build.sbt file I have successfully skipped the resolution AFTER I have a populated ivy cache https://gist.github.com/sammyrulez/7cd0aa8714c5867016209745e6969c30